# Sed substitution for text

Tags: regex, linux, bash, text, sed

I have this kind of text:

```
0
4.496
4.496
Plain text.
7.186
Plain text
10.949
Plain text
12.988
Plain text
16.11
Plain text
17.569
Plain text
ESP:
Plain text
```

I am trying to make a `sed` substitution because I need all aligned after the numbers, something like:

```
0
4.496
4.496 Plain text.
7.186 Plain text
10.949 Plain text
12.988 Plain text
16.11 Plain text
17.569 Plain text ESP:Plain text
```

But I'm trying with different combinations of commands with `sed` but I can't keep a part of the matching pattern

```
sed -r 's/\([0-9]+\.[0-9]*\)\s*/\1/g'
```

I am trying to remove all `\n` after the numbers and align the text, but it does not work. I need to align text with text too.

I tried this as well:

```
sed -r 's/\n*//g'
```

But without results.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. Your approach does not work because sed operates in a line-based manner (it reads a line, runs the code, reads another line, runs the code, and so forth), so it doesn't see the newlines unless you do special things. We'll have to completely override sed's normal control flow.

With GNU sed:

```
sed ':a $!{ N; /\n[0-9]/ { P; s/.*\n//; }; s/\n/ /; ba }' filename
```

This works as follows:

```
:a                # Jump label for looping (we'll build our own loop, with
                  # black jack and...nevermind)
$! {              # Unless the end of the input was reached:
  N               # fetch another line, append it to what we already have
  /\n[0-9]/ {     # if the new line begins with a number (if the pattern space
                  # contains a newline followed by a number)
    P             # print everything up to the newline
    s/.*\n//      # remove everything before the newline
  }
  s/\n/ /         # remove the newline if it is still there
  ba              # go to a (loop)
}
                  # After the end of the input we drop off here and implicitly
                  # print the last line.
```

The code can be adapted to work with BSD sed (as found on *BSD and Mac OS X), but BSD sed is a bit picky about labels and jump instructions. I believe

```
sed -e ':a' -e '$!{ N; /\n[0-9]/ { P; s/.*\n//; }; s/\n/ /; ba' -e '}' filename
```

should work.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But I can't reach the result because it becomes to a infinite loop and all aligned to the same line, I don't know why :S

Comment: That's odd; it works for me with the input you provided. Does the file have Windows line endings? (wild guess) Although it still shouldn't be able to become an infinite loop with that.

Comment: No no, I am working with Ubuntu. The only thing is the encoding, I am encoding at 'latin-1' , but I think this doesn't affect at all, right?

Comment: It shouldn't, no. You're not using double quotes instead of single quotes around the sed code or anything, are you? I'm trying to figure out what special thing you could do so that this code could become an infinite loop. You could try to run `LC_ALL=C sed '...' filename`, though, just to rule out the possibility that locale plays a role.

Comment: OK! It works If I try `LC_ALL=C sed '...' filename`, but can't understand why became an infinite loop. Anyway, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This gnu-awk command can also handle this:

```
awk -v RS= 'BEGIN{ FPAT="(^|\n)[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?(\n[^0-9][^\n]*)*" }
   {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {f=$i; sub(/^\n/, "", f); gsub(/\n/, " ", f); print f}}' file
0
4.496
4.496 Plain text.
7.186 Plain text
10.949 Plain text
12.988 Plain text
16.11 Plain text
17.569 Plain text ESP: Plain text
```

Comment: the request was to use [sed]  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;$!b
         x;s/\n\([^0-9]\)/ \1/gp' YourFile
```

- `-n`: print only at demand
- `'1h;1!H;$!b;x`load the whole file in buffer until the end (at the end the whole file is in work buffer)
- `s/\n\([^0-9]\)/ \1/gp`: replace all new line followed by a non digit character by a space character and print the result.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n\([[:alpha:]]\)/ \1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Process two lines at a time. If the second line begins with an alphabetic character, remove the preceeding newline and append another line and repeat. If the second line does not begin with an alphabetic character, print and then delete the first line and its newline. The second line now becomes the first line and the process repeats.